# Uploading file in document library exceeds limit in sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload

We have a file upload limit set to 50 MB and we want to upload file of 90 MB..So if we increase the upload limit to 100MB and upload the file and then set the limit back to 50MB.. is this a right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that works.  If this is a one time thing then that's fine.  If it happens more often, then setting a higher default max upload size will make more sense.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for your reply, but what happens if we upload the 90MB file and then set the limit back to 50MB... but now we go and check in and check out the file..would it throw an error saying(the file exceeds limit)..Thanks!

Comment: Check out should not cause an issue, but checking it in most likely will. I haven't hit a max file size error as we have it set pretty high so I can't say with 100% certainty.